# Convert MATLAB script to find element positions satisfying more criteria

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, matlab

I am new in this community so forgive me if this is a sort of re-post. 
I am trying to convert this MATLAB script:

```
v_i = find(rect_xmin <= Xv & Xv <= rect_xmax & rect_ymin <= Yv & Yv <= rect_ymax)
```

in Mathematica. What it does (or at least it seems so to me) is to find the element positions in the two column vectors, Xv and Yv, satisfying the specified criteria.
What I did so far is this:

```
 intx = DeleteCases[
  Flatten[Position[Xv, _?(xrectmin <= # <= xrectmax &)]], 1]; 
inty = 
 DeleteCases[Flatten[Position[Yv, _?( yrectmin <= # <= yrectmax &)]], 
  1];

pointpos = Intersection[intx, inty];
```

But it results in a vector of 800 elements, while there should be 400.
Could you help me to understand what is wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `Position[xv, x_ /; xrectmin <= x <= xrectmax]`, and similarly for `yv`? I'm not really clear on what the `Flatten` and `DeleteCases` are for...

Comment: I used Flatten and DeleteCases justto get rid of some brackets. Now I try your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, same result.

Comment: Then you really need to post more details (like: what are `Xv` `Yv`, `xrectmin` and `yrectmin`; what output _precisely_ are you looking for) because that code will give you the positions of the elements that satisfy the conditions. If that's not what you want, please be clear what you _do_ want.

Comment: Basically, I want to translate that Matlab script (the first one) into a Mathematica script. 
What that script does is to find the position of the elements that satisfy the 4 conditions all together. Xv and Yv are column vectors containing a lot of numbers, let´s say from -100 to 100. xrectmin, xrectmax, as well as yrectmin, yrectmax set the limit for those conditions. For instance, (-10,10) for x and (-40,40) for y. 
I hope is clear :/

Comment: `Intersection[Flatten@Position[xv, x_ /; xrectmin <= x <= xrectmax], 
 Flatten@Position[yv, y_ /; yrectmin <= y <= yrectmax]]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's make some sample data:

```
xmin = 0.; ymin = 0.;
xmax = 0.4; ymax = 0.3;

points = RandomReal[1, {100, 2}];
```

#### With pattern matching

This is a classical and straightforward way using pattern matching. It is very Mathematica-like:

```
Position[points, {x_, y_} /; xmin <= x <= xmax && ymin <= y <= ymax]
(* {{5}, {28}, {39}, {44}, {52}, {54}, {55}, {58}, {63}, {72}, {75}} *)
```

Timing with 5 million points: 7.01 s.

#### With regions

```
reg = Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}];

memberFun = RegionMember[reg];

Position[memberFun[points], True]
(* {{5}, {28}, {39}, {44}, {52}, {54}, {55}, {58}, {63}, {72}, {75}} *)
```

Timing with 5 million points: 0.42 s.

#### With BoolEval

A MATLAB-ish way with my [BoolEval package](https://bitbucket.org/szhorvat/booleval/overview):

```
<< BoolEval`

{xcoord, ycoord} = Transpose[points];

SparseArray[
  BoolEval[xmin <= xcoord <= xmax && ymin <= ycoord <= ymax]
]["NonzeroPositions"]
(* {{5}, {28}, {39}, {44}, {52}, {54}, {55}, {58}, {63}, {72}, {75}} *)
```

Timing with 5 million points: 0.019 s.

Comment: This seems a very useful answer. Thank you! Just the time to test them and I´ll let you know.

Comment: They work fine. Thank you.